# oAuth 2 for authorization and automatic login

Tags: javascript, php, oauth, oauth-2.0

I've been trying to wrap my head around oAuth 2. We have a self-designed single sign on system in place for authenticating users using our domain to our customers' wordpress environments. It works but it is not the most scalable solution.

So I've reading up on oAuth 2 in the hope it could replace my functionality.

Using this library it seams the server-side part is easy enough: http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/

But what I would like to achieve is the same functionality as Facebook Connect has. Authorize once in our domain - using a popup - and when authorized/logged-in in our domain get logged in into the Wordpress (or whatever) site the customer is using. 
When the user returns the next day he or she should be automatically loggedin to the client's website again.

I've seen the same functionality on goodreads.com.

How would I set up the server and client side logic to handle this. I've seen FB use a client side Facebook Connect js script.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [OpenID](http://openid.net/), it's more suitable for your Single Sign On implementation. You'll need to set up your own OpenID provider with a library like [SimpleID](http://simpleid.koinic.net/).